# TCPDF display 6 images on page

Tags: pdf, tcpdf

I'm trying to display 6 pictures on 1 page in my PDF, generated bij TCPDF. They need to have some spacing in between them, see screenshot for an example. The border and shadow are not possible in TCPDF. But I would like to have an background color if the image is not big enough to fill the space.

I tried doing this in a table using the `TCPDF->writeHTMLCell`, but I can' get any spacing between the images. See this snippet:

```
$html = '<table style="padding: 5px">
     <tr>
          <td style="background-color: #dddddd; text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff">
               <img src="'.K_PATH_IMAGES.'images/14791274972ac029eebd063d866de6e84ea331bcb6.jpg" height="180px" />
          </td>
          <td style="background-color: #dddddd; text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff">
               <img src="'.K_PATH_IMAGES.'images/147912798254e05b77141c7c8ad42747697b5d6106.png" height="180px" />
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>';
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', false);
```

I also tried it using TCPDF->Image(), but also couldn't get that to work. I couldn't position them in the right place.

```
$pdf->Image(
     K_PATH_IMAGES."images/14791274972ac029eebd063d866de6e84ea331bcb6.jpg", 
     $x = 0, 
     $y = 0, 
     $w = 0, 
     $h = 125, 
     $type = '', 
     $link = '', 
     $align = '', 
     $resize = true, 
     $dpi = 300, 
     $palign = 'C', 
     $ismask = false, 
     $imgmask = false, 
     $border = 0,
     $fitbox = 'CT', 
     $hidden = false, 
     $fitonpage = true
);
$pdf->Image(
     K_PATH_IMAGES."images/14791274972ac029eebd063d866de6e84ea331bcb6.jpg", 
     $x = 0, 
     $y = 125, 
     $w = 0, 
     $h = 125, 
     $type = '', 
     $link = '', 
     $align = '', 
     $resize = true, 
     $dpi = 300, 
     $palign = 'C', 
     $ismask = false, 
     $imgmask = false, 
     $border = 0,
     $fitbox = 'CT', 
     $hidden = false, 
     $fitonpage = true
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, after a few more tries I finally got it. This is the code I used in my foreach (stripped down for readability):

```
$pdf->Rect(
    $x_position, //11 or 110
    $y_position, //is 50, 127 or 204
    90, 
    68, 
    'F', 
    array(), 
    array(240, 240, 240)
);
$pdf->Image(
    K_PATH_IMAGES."images/".$blok["image"], 
    $x_position, //11 or 110
    $y_position, //is 50, 127 or 204
    90, //width
    68, //height
    '', //type
    '', //link
    '', //align
    false, //resize
    300, //dpi
    '', //palign
    false, //ismask
    false, //imgmask
    0, //border
    'CM', //fitbox
    false, //hidden
    false //fitonpage
);
```

The TCPDF->Rect is for the background color, the TCPDF->Image displays the image.